# Is it possible to correctly convert Float32Array to Int32Array without testing each float?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, typed-arrays

I'm currently using the following code to convert a `Float32Array` to an `Int32Array` for audio processing.

```
const int32 = new Int32Array(
  [...new Float32Array(buffer)].map((float) => {
      return float < 0 ? float * 32768 : float * 32767
})
```

Notice the ternary which checks if the float is less than `0`, if true multiplies the float by `32768`, else if false multiples the float by `32767`.

There are different vaersions of that code in the wild, e.g.,  the above is the way I wound up writing this https://github.com/zhuker/lamejs/commit/e18447fefc4b581e33a89bd6a51a4fbf1b3e1660

> # Usage with Float32Array / AudioBuffer
>
> Some libraries (such as `AudioBuffer.getChannelData()` from the
> WebAudio API) provide audio data as a `Float32Array` with values
> between `-1.0` and `1.0`. lamejs expects values between `-32768` and
> `32767`, so the values have to be mapped:
>
> ```
> var floatSamples = new Float32Array(44100); // Float sample from an external source
> var samples = new Int32Array(floatSamples.length);
> for (var i = 0; i < floatSamples.length; i++) {
>  samples[i] = floatSamples[i] < 0 ? floatSamples[i] * 32768 : floatSamples[i] * 32767;
> }
> ```

See also this post which converts `Float32Array` to `Int16Array` https://github.com/zhuker/lamejs/issues/55#issuecomment-1959182758

```
// Interpolate to -32768 to 32767, which is signed int16
const interpolated = leftChannel.map((n) =>
  Math.max(-32768, Math.min(32768, n * (n < 0 ? 32768 : 32767)))
);
```

What I'm trying to do is find out the shortest code, in characters, to achieve the expected result.

Is there are way to perform this conversion correctly without checking each individual float in the `Float32Array`?

Comment: You want shortest code or most efficient one? Because you can alias `let m = Math.max, n = Math.min; a = -32768, b = 32767, [...]` and than doing `m(a,n(b,c*(c<0?b:c)))`.

Comment: It... kinda sounds like you want to ask lame.js to just include a conversion function so that the problem is solved _by them_ instead of by thousands of users individually every single time? (even if that's just an `import { floatToInt } from "lamejs";` that you then still need to add to forwarding calls)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans It's not a lame.js specific question. Audio, video, and image processing, in general, deals with `TypedArray`'s, a lot. The same case can easily be encountered processing Opus packets, or WebP images. Remove any mention of lame.js and the question stands on it's own just dealing with JavaScript `TypedArray`'s.

Comment: @Justinas The aliasing code is the same amount of code characters. Shortest code. Is the individual float comparison necessary to do it right?

Comment: Sort of, but the post is still pretty specific to _this_ particular use-case, because not everything has a [-1,1] domain.

Comment: No, the question is a general JavaScript `TypedArray` conversion question. That I happen to come across processing audio. Nonethesless, I included the `web-audio-api` tag, anyway, so people who decided to comment or answer the question understand the context. The question is does each float have to be compared to achieve correct conversion?

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: @jabaa Can you kindly explain why in a formal answer?

Comment: What do you mean with _"why"_? It's not possible, because there is no way to do this. You have to check and convert each value.

Comment: Precisely that. The why it's not possible. The details.

Comment: The given logic requires to check and convert each separate value. There is no logic to do this in one step. How would you manipulate an array of elements without iterating over the array in JavaScript?

Comment: Alright, I see we aren't going any further on that matter. Is there a shorter way to write the comparison? How? Like this `new Float32Array(new Uint8Array(data).buffer)`. We can create a `Float3Array` from the `buffer` of a `Uint8Array`. It gets  complicated when we do the same this with `Float32Array` to `Int32Array` or `Int16Array`.

Comment: That's a completely new question. Please don't ask new questions in the comment section.

Comment: @jabaa Feel free to move along, without rancor, if you don't get the gist of the question in its entirety, which you appear not to. _"What I'm trying to do is find out the shortest code, in characters, to achieve the expected result."_

Comment: Stack Overflow is a community driven question and answer platform for specific questions. You've asked one question in the question: _"Is it possible to correctly convert Float32Array to Int32Array without testing each float?"_. You've asked another question in the comment section: _"What I'm trying to do is find out the shortest code, in characters, to achieve the expected result."_. That doesn't work here. Don't ask a question here, if you don't want feedback from other users.

Comment: I'll do whatever I want anywhere in the known universe. Again, feel free to kindly move along. You've provided your individual feedback.

Comment: @jabaa Shorter variable names I know, I'm talking about shorter code in its entirety. _"`f*32768` can be replaced with a left shift `f<<15`"_ That's what I'm talking about. Why didn't you just post that instead of all the _"how this community works"_ stuff? You understood the question from the get-go.

Comment: Ask this question on code golf to get the shortest code.

Comment: I did https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/271654/31257. The content of my question here has two parts. The shortest code part is the why I asked the question in the first place given what I posted in OP works. The why we can't directly pass a `Float32Array` `buffer` to an `Int32Array` part and get the same result is what I asked you to post as a formal answer, which you decided to not do, either because you don't know _why_ and how to explain the why in your answer, or some other undisclosed reason; I think the former.

Comment: The _"why"_ is because you can't modify the elements of an array in one step in JavaScript in one step. JavaScript doesn't allow access to raw data like e.g. C or C++, where you could use memcpy or memset. That means, you have to iterate over all elements.

Comment: @jabaa We can though in some cases `new Float32Array(new Uint8Array(data).buffer)`.

Comment: @jabaa This `Int32Array.from(new Float32Array(buffer),f=>f<<15-(f<0)*f)` doesn't work. This https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/271654/shortest-float32array-to-int32array-conversion-for-audio-processing?noredirect=1#comment587537_271654 `Int32Array.from(new Float32Array(buffer),f=>f*32768)` does.

Comment: @jabaa _"It's `(f<<15)-(f<0)*f`. You shouldn't use code that you don't understand or know why it works."_ That doesn't produce the correct result, either. Mayonnaise calling milk white. And literally impossible in the domain of programming. If that were the case all code would be perfect the first time you write it, with no bugs ever occurring nor any improvements ever necessary.

Comment: I would be really surprised if positive and negative audio would use different scales. Just ignore the off-by-one, multiply your floats by `1<<15` and clamp to the valid `Int16Array` range.

Comment: @Bergi What do you mean by _"multiply your floats by `1<<15`"_? This is the correct result `[-3276, 32767]` given `new Float32Array([-0.1, 1.0])` and using the code at OP https://gist.github.com/guest271314/15f027b20e2eaa082976f3a931cc5d2b. `Int32Array.from(floats, f => f * 1<<15);` returns `[0, 32768]`. We notice imperfections in audio, can't hide glitches, clipping, gaps in playack in pixels.

Comment: @guest271314 I said you should [clamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clamping_(graphics)) your values to `int16`. I really doubt you can hear the difference between `32766` and `32767`.

Comment: @Bergi You can hear the difference when clipping, gaps, and glitches occur in audio processing. There's no way to hide or disguise audio processing imperfections. Even the code I'm using produces clipping, not worse than the alternatives. Can you post what you are describing in code in a comment for me to test? Compare the result of using `AudioWorklet` and `MediaStreamTrackProcessor` in the branches.  `AudioWorklet` is more detail to work on Firefox and Chrome, though produces more quality result consistently https://github.com/guest271314/MP3Recorder.

Comment: `Int16Array.from(floats, f => Math.min((1<<15)-1, Math.max(-1<<15, f * (1<<15))))`

Comment: Still getting clipping using `MediaStreamTrackProcessor` that I don't get using `AudioWorklet`. Basically I have confirmed what I suspected, there's no way to directly convert between a `Float32Array` and a `Int32Array`, or `Int16Array`, either.

Comment: @Bergi Alright, I got rid of the clipping in the `MediaStreamTrackPrcessor` version by changing the bitrate to `192`. What remains is there is no specified way to convert or cast from `Float32Array` to `Int32Array`, and to do so using approaches in the wild requires processing each float individually.

Answer (score -2):

Doesn't look like there is a way to directly convert floats to integers or integers to floats - correctly - without iterating over all values in a `TypedArray`.

[Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil) was kind enough to locate and share this blog post which contains a few conversion algorithms used by applications that deal with sound [Int->Float->Int: It's a jungle out there!](http://blog.bjornroche.com/2009/12/int-float-int-its-jungle-out-there.html)

| # | Int to Float | Float to Int<sup>*</sup> | Transparency | Used By |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0) | `((integer + .5)/(0x7FFF+.5)` | `float*(0x7FFF+.5)-.5` | Up to at least 24-bit | DC DAC Modeled |
| 1) | `(integer / 0x8000)` | `float * 0x8000` | Up to at least 24-bit | Apple (Core Audio)<sup>1</sup>, ALSA<sup>2</sup>, MatLab<sup>2</sup>, sndlib<sup>2</sup> |
| 2) | `(integer / 0x7FFF)` | `float * 0x7FFF` | Up to at least 24-bit | Pulse Audio<sup>2</sup> |
| 3) | `(integer / 0x8000)` | `float * 0x7FFF` | Non-transparent | PortAudio<sup>1,2</sup>, Jack<sup>2</sup>, libsndfile<sup>1,3</sup> |
| 4) | `(integer>0?integer/0x7FFF:integer/0x8000)` | `float>0?float*0x7FFF:float*0x8000` | Up to at least 24-bit | At least one high end DSP and A/D/A manufacturer.<sup>2,4</sup> XO Wave 1.0.3. |
| 5) | Unknown | `float*(0x7FFF+.49999)` | Unknown | ASIO2 |

<sup>*</sup>obviously, rounding or dithering may be required here.
Note that in the case of IO APIs, drivers are often responsible for conversions. The conversions listed here are provided by the API.

Edited December 6, 2009: Fixed Method 3. (0x8000 and 0x7FFF were backwards)

Sources:
<sup>1</sup> Mailing list
<sup>2</sup> Perusing the source code (this, of course, is subject to mistakes due to following old, conditional or optional code)
<sup>3</sup> libsndfile FAQ goes into detail about this.
<sup>4</sup> Personal communication.
Posted by [Bjorn Roche](https://www.blogger.com/profile/17072425815152893296) at [1:51 PM](http://blog.bjornroche.com/2009/12/int-float-int-its-jungle-out-there.html)

Comment: "*Doesn't look like there is a way to directly convert floats to integers or integers to floats without iterating over all values*" - that's kinda obvious, no?

Comment: @Bergi No, not obvious. I made sure that fact is known, unambiguously, for JavaScript programmers who might happen to encounter this case now and in the future.